# Z-index not working

Tags: javascript, css

Take a look at this page I'm working on: http://s361608839.websitehome.co.uk/textcube/

The nav bar is going behind the slider and I wanted it to sit above instead. I've tried setting a high z-index on the #navbar and #navbar-inner and nothing happened.

```
#navbar{
background: url(../images/nav-bg.png) repeat-x;
height: 55px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
z-index: 9999;
}
#navbar-inner{
width: 912px;
margin: 0 auto;
position: relative;
z-index: 9999;
}
```

I think the javascript slider using CSS style .bx-window and .bx-window are the cause however I have set a low z-index on both, yet I don't see any difference.

Help with this would definately be appeciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`z-index` works only with positioned elements (`position:absolute`, `position:relative`).

Here's an article http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#z-index

In your case, you forgot to add `position` to one of your element.

Comment: Or `relative`, without breaking the intended layout.

Comment: @Kolink, thanks, I edited my answer, I've mistakenly put "position:absolute" instead of positioned.

Answer (score 1):

Add `position:relative` to `#navbar`

Answer (score 1):

It works with either float:... or position:...