# Z-indexing on ionic elements

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I'm developping a mobile/web app with Ionic Framework. I'm using a custom CSS header and a `ion-slide-box`, customized the pager but want it to overlap with this custom header.

I tried everything with positioning and `z-index`, but I can't manage to show the pager over the CSS shape.

**The Code:**

```css
.bandeau
{
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  height: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #555555;
  margin-bottom: 80px;
}
.oval {
  -moz-border-radius: 100px / 50px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100px / 50px;
  border-radius: 60% / 30px;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  top: 60%;
  background-color: #555555;
}
.slider-pager {
  display: block;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
  top: -30px;
  height: 48px;
}
.slider-pager .slider-pager-page {
  position: relative;
  background-color: gray;
  border-radius: 100%;
  max-width: 72px;
  width: 48px;
  z-index: 10;
  height: 100%;
}
.pager-image {
  width: 100%;
}
.slider {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: white;
}
.ion-slide {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="bandeau">
  <div class="oval"></div>
</div> <!-- TODO -->
<ion-nav-view name="menuContent" animation="slide-left-right"></ion-nav-view>

<ion-view view-title="Catspads" align-title="left">
  <ion-slide-box show-pager="true">
    <ion-slide>
      <ion-content>
```

**Screenshot (here the pager won't be over the header):**
[image: Here the pager won't be over the header.]

Comment: You seem to miss a lot of closing tags in your html snippet...

Comment: Did you give some `position` to all z-indexed elements AND their parent elements (`position: relative`, if no alteration wanted) ➝ http://stackoverflow.com/a/7493730/444255

Comment: Yes, I can't paste the generated code as it's done through angular and ionic, so i'm just giving the global architecture of the html. It's more a CSS issue imo.

Comment: @Frank N: Everything is positionned as you said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I found to get rid of this was to programatically move the pager using JS to an upper HTML level, positionning it out of the `ion-content` tag. `z-index` worked as intended, but couldn't find a cleaner solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

The z-index on the header for me was 999. When I used a z-index 1000, everything worked.